# DRBD /dev/drbd0 not showing : mysql stopped

Tags: centos6, high-availability, drbd, corosync

I have two Xen virtual servers with mysql cluster(db1 and db2) with **DRBD and corosync**.

Recently one of the server i upgrade to KVM and i configured drbd `*.res` file to be sync again and its working. But the issue is the `mysql` mounted partition is not showing with the command:

`$ df -hT`

```
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda     ext3    8.6G  3.9G  4.4G  47% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    2.0G   23M  2.0G   2% /dev/shm
```

But here `/dev/drbd0` should also be shown on `/var/lib/mysql`.

`$service drbd status` shows the following on both servers:

[image]

`$clustat` showing: (I turned off the second server)

```
 Member Name      ID   Status
 ------ ----      ---- ------
 db1               1 Online, Local
 db2               2 Offline
```

I also tried to make db1 as primary server with `drbdadm` but no luck. Please advise.

Comment: Corosync is responsible for mounting the device on the given path. You should not be trying to promote a resource manually when failover is managed by corosync. You will have to manage this through corosync. I am not sure on how to do this but restarting corosync might work.

Comment: `corosync` is running on db1 server and failed to start at db2. i switched off db2 but still not working